# PostgreSQL Error handling with full details

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have built a function in PostgreSQL which performs Insert/update of about 200 fields.

I have included an exception handling code which just says

```
Exception when others  then
raise notice '% %',SQLERRM,SQLSTATE;
```

Problem is this is not displaying the error in details. 
For example, during insert, one of the fields is `int` and we are passing `varchar`, it displays the error but not showing due to which field it is causing the error. Is it possible to show this?

Comment: Yes, see "43.6.8.1. Obtaining Information About An Error" in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html for what error data you can get.

Comment: did you use the GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS command to get Error Diagnostics Items?, you can see the doc here : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING